# How to write a multithreads model with emf?

Tags: java, multithreading, eclipse-emf

I am writting a multithreads program with java, so in my emf model that some class need implements the Runnable class, so i wondered how to do this with emf? 
such as:

```
public interface MyClass extends Runnable {
```

rather than:

```
public interface MyClass extends EObject {
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note EMF Core itself is not thread safe, two options are existing : 
EMF-CDO which allow concurrent modifications with transactions
EMF-Transaction which allow you to control the way changes are being made spliting those into TransactionalCommands, the changes are not really applied concurrently though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an up-to-date EMF install to hand, but the EMF book (ed 2) says that you do this by changing the "Model Class Defaults>Root extends Interface" property in your GenModel.

However, I have my doubts that using `Runnable` will work.  Maybe you should define your own interface that extends both `Runnable` and `EObject` ?

Comment: thanks, i got it.The solution is add a abstract interface class in emf, and make this class extends java.lang.Runnable class, then have a class implements this class, after generating codes, then you can see it's implements the Runnable class rather than the interface class itself!